Expected value of this distribution
Let $a>0$ and let $X$ be a random variable with pdf $f(x)=\begin{cases}2\phi_\sigma(x)+\frac{\theta}{a}&\text{if $0\leq x \leq a$}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$, where

$\phi_\sigma(x)$ is the pdf of the normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$,
$\Phi_\sigma(x)$ is the associated cdf,
and $\theta:=1-\Phi_\sigma(a)+\Phi_\sigma(-a)$

I am trying to find the expected value of $X$.
What I have is
$$
E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)dx \\
= \int_0^a x \left( 2\phi_\sigma(x)+\frac{\theta}{a} \right) dx \\
= 2\int_0^ax\phi_\sigma(x)dx + \frac{\theta}{a}\int_0^axdx \\
= 2\sigma\frac{\phi_\sigma(0)-\phi_\sigma(\frac{a}{\sigma})}{\Phi_\sigma(\frac{a}{\sigma})-\Phi_\sigma(0)}+\theta \frac{a}{2}
$$
I ran some sanity checks on this, and there are some discrepancies:

As $a$ approaches infinity, $f$ should approach $\phi_\sigma$, so $E$ should approach $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sigma$. However, in actual fact, $\lim_{a \to \infty}E=2\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sigma$.
As $\sigma$ approaches infinity, the influence of the normally-distributed part should decrease, and $f$ should approach pdf of the uniform distribution $\mathcal{U}_{[0, a]}$. However, when I graph $E$ as a function of $\sigma$, it stays constant at first, then actually rises to a peak, before falling off and approaching $0$.

I have triple-checked my math, but I can't see where I went wrong. Would be grateful for help.
NB: This is related to my earlier question Expected value of normally distributed random variable with "reroll", in case anybody wants more background on what this is for. $X$ is the absolute of the random variable discussed there. I don't think it's strictly needed in the context of the question, though.

The first integral is
$$
2\int_0^a x \phi_\sigma(x) dx \\
= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \int_0^a x e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}x^2} dx \\
= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\left(  \sigma^2 - \sigma^2 e^{-\frac{a^2}{2\sigma^2} } \right) \\
= \sigma \sqrt\frac{2}{\pi} \left( 1 - e^{-\frac{a^2}{2\sigma^2}} \right)
$$
